# Python - Rotations of digits

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create code that will take a given integer, then output a set of integers, all of which are rotations of digits of the input integer.

Thus, if I inputted '197', the output should be '197', '971', and '791'.

However, when I try:

```
def rotation(n):
  rotations = set()
  for i in range( len( str(n) ) ):
    n = int( str(n)[i:] + str(n)[:i] )
    rotations.add(n)
```

with the input '197', it only returns '197', '971', yet NOT '791'.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Just curious, why do you not want 179, 917 and, 719?

Comment: Either reassign `n` (and work with element at index `0`), or work with the index `i` (and assign the result to a temp variable. Don't do both. Write what you are trying to do on a piece of paper, you''ll understand. :)

Comment: @YunkaiXiao he wants rotations, not permutations.

Comment: @Jérôme Then it would be 719 not 791 right?

Comment: @YunkaiXiao right. This is an error in the OP I didn't notice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there. Except you're erasing the input n at each iteration. Use another variable name.

```
def rotation(n):
  rotations = set()
  for i in range( len( str(n) ) ):
    m = int( str(n)[i:] + str(n)[:i] )
    rotations.add(m)
  return rotations

print(rotation(197))
```

I would write it more like this, using a set comprehension:

```
def rotation(number):
    str_number = str(number)
    return {
        int( str_number[i:] + str_number[:i] )
        for i in range(len(str_number))
    }
```

Solution 2 by @Henry Woody is nice too. Rather than rotate input string by `i` at each iteration, rotate by `1` from last iteration.

Comment: Haha, I was about to post this answer with the only difference that I used x instead of m :)

Comment: (Or get rid of the variable altogether)

Answer (score 1):

The way you have your code structured does duplicate rotation because you reassign `n` on each step of the loop and use the iteration variable `i` in your slices.

So the process in the loop from your example is:

- `i = 0`

  - You have `n = 197` and the rotation logic does nothing with `i = 0` so you add `197` to rotations
- `i = 1`

  - Again you have `n = 197`, and rotation logic makes `n = 971` and you add that to `rotations`.
- `i = 2`

  - Now `n = 971`, and the rotation logic slices from index `2`, but `n` has already been rotated so we have `n = 197` again, which is added to `rotations` (and removed since `rotations` is a set). Basically `n` has already been rotated forward, and now it is being rotated forward 2 steps (back to the initial value and skipping over `n = 719`)

To fix this you can either:

**1.** Keep `n` at its initial value and on each step rotate `n` the full amount (`i`) and add that to `rotation` without modifying `n`. Like so:

```
def rotation(n):
  rotations = set()
  for i in range( len( str(n) ) ):
    rotations.add(int( str(n)[i:] + str(n)[:i] ))
  return rotations
```

**2.** Rotate `n` forward on each step, but only rotate it forward one position each time. Like so:

```
def rotation(n):
  rotations = set()
  for i in range( len( str(n) ) ):
    n = int( str(n)[1:] + str(n)[:1] )
    rotations.add(n)
  return rotations
```